# Can we know when browser finish loading an URL from application on Android

Tags: android, browser, android-webview

I Have an app, and from app I use this code to open URL in browser of android.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
             Uri.parse("http://www.mkyong.com"));
        startActivity(intent);

    }

});
```

And i want to know if we can know when browser complete loading that URL from code.
Thank you!

Comment: You have to put `webview` in your own app and then override `onPageFinished` of webview Client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use webview! You will get much control while using webview as users will stay within your application, even if they are showing an external page.
(Still you won't  be able to get control over the actions performed in the html loaded, for example the buttons clicked in the web view.)

```
boolean loadingFinished = true;
boolean redirect = false;

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
       if (!loadingFinished) {
          redirect = true;
       }

   loadingFinished = false;
   view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
   return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
        loadingFinished = false;
        //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE  
    }

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       if(!redirect){
          loadingFinished = true;
       }

       if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
         //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
       } else{
          redirect = false; 
       }

    }
});
```

Comment: So if I dont use webview, there's no way to know when browser finish loading an url,right ?

Comment: I don't think we can track the activities happening in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you load your page by using webview then when the page loading is complete onPageFinished method will call and you can perform your action in that method.below is the code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView myBrowser;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dropdown_html); 
    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser); 
    myBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.mkyong.com"); 
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {     

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Your page loading is finish.
    }
}
```

}